# Sorting a JScript Array on a String Field with leading No.s

Tags: javascript, spservices

I have a JS object, with an internal array of another JS object. The internal onw is like

```
function outerObj()
{
    this.items = new Array();
    this.clear = function () {
        this.items = new Array();
    }
    function __item(v1, v2, v3, v4) {
        this.Val_1 = v1;
        this.Val_2 = v2;
        this.Val_3 = v3;
        this.Val_4 = v4;
    }
    this.add = function (vA, vB, vC, vD) {
        this.items.push( new __item(vA, vB, vC, vD) );
    }
    ...
}
```

The array is loaded through an SPServices `getListItems()` call, using `.each( . . . )` on the resultant XML.  The results are ordered (`<OrderBy>`), but the results are the common irritation:

```
1
10
11
2
21
3
42A
42B
```

I cannot get away from the inclusion of letters (this is the name of real-world items), while I want the sort to be

```
1
2
3
10
11
21
42A
42B
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You need to use a sorting algorithm with parseInt() inside the tests on values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use javascript array.sort()

code would look like this:

```
this.items.sort()
```

Heres a link: [Javascript sort reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: actually, it would look like

    this.items.sort(function v1, v2) { /* algorythm here */ });

The algorythm is where I can add the intelligence that is aware of the fact that the array is holding objects, not values, and where i can really examine the property upon which i am sorting.

In fact, I can write an external function, and call it from the anonymous function.

Thanks Elisha; this got me on track.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Elisha, it would look like this.

```
    items.sort(function (v1, v2) { 
        /* algorythm here */ 
    });
```

The algorythm is where I can add the intelligence that is aware of the fact that the array is holding objects, not values, and where i can really examine the property upon which i am sorting.

In fact, I can write an external function, and call it from the anonymous function.

Thanks Elisha; this got me on track.

I am answering here, so that I can use the ability to format the answer.  But Elisha should get the credit on this one.

Incidentally, the function needs to return a negative number, zero, or a positive number. The *sign* of what is returned indicates the sorting order between the two arguments passed in.